# Is it possible to get a snowglobe from the Frost Legion?

Tags: terraria

I got a snowglobe by presents yesterday.[Note that I changed the date on my IOS to 25th of December]
I summoned the Frost Legion but got no extra snowglobe compared to the pirate attacks where you get a pirate map from a pirate.
So is it a chance you can get a snowglobe from a snowman?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wiki lists presents as the only source of Snowglobes.

> [It can be obtained from opening Presents in Hardmode worlds during the Christmas season (December 15th through 31st, based on your computer's time setting.), but can be used in any world at any time.](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Snow_Globe)

Seeing as the Christmas event ends on December 31st, yet you can still summon the Frost Legion during other times, it would make sense that they would not allow the "loophole" of the Legion dropping Globes, as this would effectively make them constantly summonable at any time of year.

Comment: It also said in the wikis it is the Christmas equivalent of the pirate attack.

Comment: But in the pirate attack I got killed, while when battling the Frost Legion I never got killed

Comment: @DetectiveRT Christmas equivalent meaning it doesn't make sense to have it available during other times of the year when there is...an equivalent (the pirates).  And I'm not sure what dying has to do with anything...